# How to prove the reversion of a doubling function equals the doubling of a reversion function in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

I have a function that doubles the elements of a list in the form

```
double [x1, x2, ...] = [x1, x1, x2, x2, ...]
```

namely

```
 fun double :: " 'a list ⇒ 'a list"
 where
   "double [] = []" |
   "double (x#xs) = x # x # double xs"
```

and a function that reverses the elements of a list with the help of another function `snoc` that adds an element to the right side of a list:

```
 fun snoc :: "'a list ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a list"
 where
   "snoc [] x = [x]" |
   "snoc (y # ys) x = y # (snoc ys x)"


 fun reverse :: "'a list ⇒ 'a list"
 where
   "reverse [] = []" |
   "reverse (x # xs) = snoc (reverse xs) x"
```

Now I want to prove that

```
 lemma rev_double: "rev (double xs) = double (rev xs)"
```

is true.

I tried to apply induction on `xs`

```
lemma rev_double: "rev (double xs) = double (rev xs)"
by (induction xs)
```

and I wrote an auxiliary lemma `double_snoc` that ensures that doubling a list is the same as doubling its first element and the rest of the list (which uses the function `snocleft` which inserts an element at the left end of a list)

```
fun snocleft::"'a list ⇒ 'a  ⇒ 'a list "
where
  "snocleft [] x = [x]" |
  "snocleft (y # ys) x =  x # (y # ys)"


lemma double_snoc: "double (snocleft xs y) = y # y # double xs"
by (induction xs) auto
```

I still haven't made any progress in proving the lemma. Do you have some solutions or hints on how to set up the prove?

Comment: Just an aside: your `snocleft` is basically just list cons (i.e., `op #` in Isabelle/HOL) with the arguments swapped. Furthermore, since no recursion is going on, `fun` is somewhat overkill. You could use definition `definition "snocleft ys y = y # ys"` (which makes it obvious that your lemma could be statet `double (x # xs) = x # x # double xs` which directly follows from the definition of `double`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your function as `reverse`, but in all of your lemmas, you use `rev`, referring to the pre-defined list reversal function `rev`.

What you mean is probably this:

```
lemma reverse_double: "reverse (double xs) = double (reverse xs)"
```

If you attempt to prove this by induction (with `apply (induction xs)`), you will get stuck in the induction case with the following goal:

```
snoc (snoc (double (reverse xs)) a) a =
   double (snoc (reverse xs) a)
```

This should be intuitively obvious: if you first snoc and then double, it is the same as first doubling and then snoc-ing twice. So let's prove this as an auxiliary lemma:

```
lemma double_snoc: "double (snoc xs x) = snoc (snoc (double xs) x) x"
  by (induction xs) auto
```

Now the proof of `reverse_double` goes through automatically:

```
lemma reverse_double: "reverse (double xs) = double (reverse xs)"
  by (induction xs) (auto simp: double_snoc)
```